# C#. How to create List with new values and different size than original List

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

For example the main data is

> Theme Author Question

:

> Sport Tyler 'Question'
>
> History Tyler 'Question'
>
> Sport Tyler 'Question'

I need to count how many questions each theme has and to show the answer i need to create another List which contains just theme and number i counted.
So it should look like this:

> Sport 2
>
> History 1

to count how many questions there is I just

```
static void Method(List<Class> list)
    {
        int sport = 0;
        int history = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].Theme == "History")
            {
                history++;
            }
            else if (list[i].Theme == "Sport")
            {
                sport++;
            }}
```

So know I'm trying to figure out how to show it through List

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by 'how to show it through list'?

Comment: I mean that after i count the questions, i need to sort out the list. So I don't know how i could sort out list, if I'm not using List array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way is use Linq and group by method like this

```
var query = from item in list
    group item by item.Theme into group
    select new { Question = group.Key, Count = group.Count()};

foreach(var item in query){
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Question, item.Count);
}

    Dictionary<string, int> themes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

But you can also use a Dictionary to store every Theme and it's count:

```
Dictionary<string, int> themes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if(themes.ContainsKey(list[i].Theme))
        themes[this[i].Theme]++;
    else
        themes[this[i].Theme = 1;
}

foreach(var keyValuePair in themes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenBy(x => x.Key)){
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

Comment: It worked for me with Dictionary, thanks. But then how could I sort out the result I got. For example descending order with counts and if counts equals than alphabetically

Comment: because if i got List array i just add IComparable in class and then list.Sort();   but here i have two separate values

Comment: I edited the answer, so the dictionary is ordered by it's count, then by the theme.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want the themes and the count? You can group your items by theme and count the number of items in each group:

```
var sportsAndCounts = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Theme)
    .Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Count()}");
```

This creates the string you're describing, but you can project the groupings to anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `Dictionary`! Just see the following code:

```
static void Theme(List<Class> list) {
     var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
     for (var current in list) {
          if (dict.ContainsKey(current.Theme) {
              dict[current.Theme]++;
          } else {
              dict[current.Theme] = 1;
          }
     }
}
```

After that you have your counts in `dict`. Just get them with e.g. `dict["History"]`

Answer (score 0):

With entity framework.. you can accomplish that

```
 var query = list.GroupBy(p => p.Theme)
               .Select(g => new { Sport = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

in the var query u should have what u pretend.

ps. didnt test the code;

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>
{
    new Question{ Theme = "Sport", Author = "Tyler", T = "Question", },
    new Question{ Theme = "History", Author = "Tyler", T = "Question", },
    new Question{ Theme = "Sport", Author = "Tyler", T = "Question", },
};

var HistoryCount = QuestionList.Count(x => x.Theme == "History");
var SportCount = QuestionList.Count(x => x.Theme == "Sport");
```

HistoryCount will be 2,
SportCount will be 1.

This will require you to reference System.Linq.